# Shift Share Decomposition for Non-Multiplicative Relationships

Tags: time-series, decomposition

Given 
$$ Y_t = \sum_i \omega_{i,t} \cdot X_{i,t}  $$

We can decompose the change in $Y$ from period $t$ to $t + 1$ into: 
$$ \begin{align} Y_{t + 1} - Y_t &= \left( \sum_i \omega_{i,t + 1} X_{i, t + 1} -  \sum_i \omega_{i,t} X_{i, t} \right) + \left( \sum_i \omega_{i,t} X_{i, t + 1} -  \sum_i \omega_{i,t} X_{i, t + 1} \right) \\
&= \underbrace{\sum_i (\omega_{i,t + 1} - \omega_{i,t}) X_{i, t + 1}}_{\text{Contribution from change in } \omega} + \underbrace{\sum_i \omega_{i,t} ( X_{i, t + 1} - X_{i, t})}_{\text{Contribution from change in } X}  
\end{align} $$

Is there a similar *exact* decomposition for when $Y_t$ is defined as below?

$$ Y_t = \frac{\sum_i X_{i,t}}{\sum_i X_{i,t}/ \omega_{i,t}} $$

The best I can think of is just looking at the difference between $Y_t$ and $Y_{t + 1}$ if only $X$ or $\omega$ changed but this decomposition isn't exact and it is difficult to interpret.

Also posted in math stack exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110756/shift-share-decomposition-for-non-multiplicative-relationships).

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: The abrupt change in notation between definition and decomposition (the subscripts appear to have been reversed) makes it unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to work out a formula in the calculus of differences?

Comment: Subscripts fixed. Thanks! 

The goal is to be able to decompose a change in $Y_t$ into a component from changes in $X$ and a component from changes in $\omega$. The best I have come up with so far is in the below answer.

Answer (score 0):

Best I have come up with so far is below. Would love to know other possibilities though.

The inverse of $Y_t$ is equal to:

$$\frac{1}{Y_t} =  \frac{\sum_i X_{i,t}/ \omega_{i,t} }{\sum_i X_{i,t}} = \sum _i \frac{X_{i,t}}{\sum_i X_{i,t}} \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t}} $$

A change in inverse $Y_t$ from time $t$ to $t + 1$ can be decomposed into (writing $X_{i,t}/ \sum_i X_{i,t}$ as $S_{i,t}$):

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{Y_{t + 1}} - \frac{1}{Y_t} &= \sum_i S_{i,t +1} \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t+1}} - \sum_i S_{i,t} \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t}} \\
&= \sum_i \left( S_{i,t +1} - S_{i,t} \right) \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t+1}} + \sum_i S_{i,t} \left( \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t+1}} - \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t}} \right) 
\end{align*}

Since the LHS is equal to $(Y_t - Y_{t  +1}) / (Y_{t + 1} \cdot Y_t)$, any change in productivity can be decomposed into:

\begin{equation}
Y_{t + 1} - Y_t =  \underbrace{- (Y_{t + 1} \cdot Y_t) \sum_i \left( S_{i,t +1} - S_{i,t} \right) \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t+1}}}_{\text{Contribution from change in } S_i} +  \underbrace{- (Y_{t + 1} \cdot Y_t)  \sum_i S_{i,t} \left( \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t+1}} - \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t}} \right)}_{\text{Contribution from change in } \omega_i} 
\end{equation}

You can also decompose inverse productivity differently and get: 
\begin{equation}
Y_{t + 1} - Y_t =  \underbrace{- (Y_{t + 1} \cdot Y_t) \sum_i \left( S_{i,t +1} - S_{i,t} \right) \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t}}}_{\text{Contribution from change in } S_i} +  \underbrace{- (Y_{t + 1} \cdot Y_t)  \sum_i S_{i,t + 1} \left( \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t+1}} - \frac{1}{\omega_{i,t}} \right)}_{\text{Contribution from change in } \omega_i} 
\end{equation}